# How to remove pre-compiled JSPs and just use JSP to serve files

Tags: jsp, struts2, precompiled

I have a legacy Struts 2 application configured as a dynamic web application in Eclipse that pre-compiles JSPs and puts them under `WEB-INF/classes/org`.

They are mapped in `web.xml` as as servlets.

I tried removing the mapping of the servlets in `web.xml` so I can normally just use the JSPs but when I try to access the following urls:

- `http://localhost:8080/jsp/index.jsp`
- `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp`

I get this error:

> **The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

The `struts.xml` maps the JSP below which looks correct:

```
<action name="index" class="com.acr.cs.action.ClassforGreat" method="index">
        <result>/jsp/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The structure of my project below

```
WebContent
-images
-jsp
-WEB-INF
```

How to make me use just the jsps and remove the pre-compiled ones?

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSPs under `WEB-INF` and create a result configs.

You don't have to access JSPs directly from the browser because they are not resources and in most cases can't run without associated filter.

They are used as a templates for generating HTML returned as a resource from the action after executing it.